# How can I change the columns in a range to column A using VBA?

Tags: range, shift

I'm attempting to change any range selection that the user makes to column A only. I would like to keep the same row selction.

```
Sub update_test()
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim SelRange As Range
Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
Set SelRange = Selection.Columns(1)
'My selected range is $S$1832:$S$1842

Debug.Print SelRange.Address
'I was hoping that the .Columns(1) would change my range to $A$1832:$A$1842
'But it is still $S$1832:$S$1842

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with offset and errors, seems a bit longwinded

```
Sub update_test()

Dim SelRange As Range
Set SelRange = Selection

Debug.Print SelRange.Address
On Error Resume Next
For i = -100 To 0 Step 1
    Set SelRange = SelRange.Offset(0, i)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then i = 0
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

Debug.Print SelRange.Address

end sub
```